# string with newline character -- copy to Qtextview

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I am trying to read a xml file. File is loaded correctly.
I am reading text of first node (i.e. 0 node) of the xml file & loading in the text edit.

Text is loaded correctly but `\n newline character` is `not converted into Actual newline` in the qtextedit.

How to save string in qt text node so that new line character is converted into actual newline when displaying it on `QTextView`?

Output on qtextedit is:

```
\n\n I am a boy \n\n From Town
```

XML file:

```
<MyMenu>
 <Index IndexName="About Me"> \n\n &lt;b> I am a boy &lt;/b> \n\n From Town </Index>
 <Index IndexName="My Education"> \n\n graduation : BSC \n\n Post graduation : MSC </Index>
</MyMenu>
```

Code to read & display xml :

```
#define FILE_NAME              "HelpContent.xml"

QString exePath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
QString helpFileCompletePath = exePath + QDir::separator() + FILE_NAME;

//set the name of the XML Help file
xmlFile.setFileName(helpFileCompletePath);
ret = xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);

xmlDomDocument.clear();
xmlDomDocument.setContent(&xmlFile);
nn = xmlDomDocument.firstChild();

list = nn.childNodes();

QDomNode e = list.at(0);
rootElementText = e.toElement().text();
ui->helpTextEdit->setText(rootElementText);
```

================= Edit: setting part of string as bold =============================

```
 <Index IndexName="About Me"> \n\n &lt;b> I am a boy &lt;/b> \n\n From Town </Index>
```

This one make the part of string "I am boy" as bold but newline is not inserted if i use the logic suggested by BartoszKP.

Now if i make string "from town" bold then in this case new line is inserted  if i use the logic suggested by BartoszKP. But "from town " is not made bold.

```
 <Index IndexName="About Me"> \n\n  I am a boy \n\n &lt;b> From Town &lt;/b>  </Index>
```

Any suggestion, how to remove this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

There are no new lines in your file, just two characters "\" and "n" that together, incidentally are interpreted in a special way by C++ compilers. There is no reason to impose this convention on all C++ programs, so Qt's classes don't interpret these characters. So "\n" in your file's content is not a C++ newline "character" as you suggest (which suggests that you are thinking about it in a wrong way) - in C++ it's equivalent to the string: `"\\n"`.

You could try this to achieve the desired result in this case, using Qt's [`QString::replace`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#replace-8):

```
rootElementText = e.toElement().text().replace("\\n", "\n");
```

However some more work would be needed to interpret all special characters.

Another straightforward solution is not to use "\n" characters in your file - just put the actual new lines (e.g. hit the "enter" key) in there:

```xml
<Index IndexName="About Me"> 

 I am a boy 

 From Town </Index>
```

Comment: yes this add the newline but still one issue .. that if i makes part of string "I am a boy" as bold then this part is displayed as bold but ... your logic to add new line character fails... ?

Comment: Please can you suggest on this ..?

Comment: @Katoch Please stop spamming with comments, and please don't change original meaning of the question. This is not a help-desk service. If you have another question, create another post.

Comment: Got the answer .... dont use \n line character for adding line break use <br/> character to add new line. Every thing will work fine with <br/>.

Comment: @Katoch this depends on configuration of your text edit. If it interprets HTML then of course some HTML tags will work.